# Nutch regex for crawl

Tags: java, web-crawler, nutch

I am using Apache Nutch to crawl the web page. I want to crawl the web  page when i search for particular name like 
    if i search bill gates i want to get the results links of that search result. I have url like

```
www.mysite.com/search?name=bill+gates
```

but in crawling it displays no more url to fetch. actually it does not fetch any results.

Is there any option to crawl that page? i have added in regex-urlfilter.txt to accept everything.
How would i crawl  the link? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my memory nutch got an extra setting for cutting off url parameters like ?q=bill+gates.
I'll think this setting is located in automaton-urlfilter.txt:

```
# skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.
-.*[?*!@=].*
```

So you got to change this line.

Hope I could help you

Comment: I crawled page where will the links are stored?

Comment: links are stored in a folder called linkdb. Nutch generates three folders: crawldb, linkdb and segments. Take a look at this page for some help: http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial

Comment: yes. If i want to fetch all the links means i need to read the linkdb right?

Comment: Hmm if you want to store the links crawled from nutch, a good possibility would be to send them automaticaly to an apache solr server. So you don't have to read the linkdb. I'll think that the entries in linkdb are compressed so that you cannot read them.

Comment: thanks i write  java code to read the content of crwaled page. It is working for normal urls. but if i add query parameter means i can not read the segments